# Accessing parent class when doing custom converter

Tags: java, javabeans, dozer

I am currently using Dozer to map to sets of objects.

I have a situation where I need to use a custom converter to map a String to TypeA.

The way I convert TypeA to a String depends on the type of Object TypeA is a member of.

Specifically TypeA has 2 fields lets call them *prefix* and *postfix*.  Sometimes I need to split the String by a space, or dash or slash.  That character to split on is defined in the parent of TypeA.

Is there a way to do this in Dozer with custom converters?  I need to go up the chain...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So far I'm thinking that I'll have to do a post-processor to clean up the destination objects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you should map a String to the parent of TypeA. In your xml file, to get to the "prefix" and "postfix" you would type, `parent.TypeA.prefix` or `parent.TypeA.postfix`. Hope this helps.